# how to set correct path for svg after change basePath in next.config.js?

Tags: next.js, configuration

I used to display svg in path "/public/assets/images/media/example.svg"
After setting basePath in next.config.js

```
basePath: '/exmplpath',
```

What should be the correct path? ("/exmplpath/public/assets/images/media/example.svg" dont work)

Comment: Where were you using the path `/public/assets/images/media/example.svg`? If you're using `next/image` to display the SVG, you'll need to add the `basePath` to the image's path, i.e. `src="/exmplpath/assets/images/media/example.svg"`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath#images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the file `next.config.js` you need to set this as

> publicRuntimeConfig : { basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH || '' }

so you can access to it by :

> import config config from 'next/config'

and then use it as variable

> const {publicRuntimeConfig} = config();

and then your path to image will be

> <img src={`${publicRuntimeConfig}/assets/images/media/example.svg`}

let me know if you know more informations or explication !